# installation error in ORB_SLAM3 on Ubuntu 18

Tags: c++, ubuntu, slam-algorithm

I am trying to install ORB_SLAM3 on Ubuntu 18... I also installed all Prerequisites but when I run  `./build.sh` I face with this error:

```
CMakeFiles/ORB_SLAM3.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/ORB_SLAM3.dir/src/System.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ORB_SLAM3.dir/src/System.cc.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/ORB_SLAM3.dir/build.make:302: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/ORB_SLAM3.dir/src/Atlas.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ORB_SLAM3.dir/src/Atlas.cc.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/ORB_SLAM3.dir/build.make:206: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/ORB_SLAM3.dir/src/FrameDrawer.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ORB_SLAM3.dir/src/FrameDrawer.cc.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/ORB_SLAM3.dir/build.make:494: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/ORB_SLAM3.dir/src/Viewer.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ORB_SLAM3.dir/src/Viewer.cc.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/ORB_SLAM3.dir/build.make:110: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/ORB_SLAM3.dir/src/LocalMapping.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ORB_SLAM3.dir/src/LocalMapping.cc.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/ORB_SLAM3.dir/build.make:470: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/ORB_SLAM3.dir/src/Initializer.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ORB_SLAM3.dir/src/Initializer.cc.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/ORB_SLAM3.dir/build.make:86: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/ORB_SLAM3.dir/src/Tracking.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ORB_SLAM3.dir/src/Tracking.cc.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/ORB_SLAM3.dir/build.make:134: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/ORB_SLAM3.dir/src/LoopClosing.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ORB_SLAM3.dir/src/LoopClosing.cc.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/ORB_SLAM3.dir/build.make:374: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/ORB_SLAM3.dir/src/Optimizer.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ORB_SLAM3.dir/src/Optimizer.cc.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:289: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/ORB_SLAM3.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ORB_SLAM3.dir/all] Error 2
```

during executing the code this error is also showed:

```
fatal error: Eigen/Core: No such file or directory
 #include <Eigen/Core>
```

could anyone do me a favor and help me with this issue!?

Comment: Have you installed eigen?

Comment: yes, I've installed Eigen do/due to this command:  sudo apt-get install libeigen3-dev

Answer (score 0):

it's been solved by replacing `#include<Eigen/Core>` to `include<eigen3/Eigen/Core>` in all files that include this library.
OR
run `sudo cp -r /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen /usr/include` in terminal instead.